# Join 2 tables give repeat value

Tags: mysql

I have a table name **tbl_folder**

```
db_id  db_foldername
1       test
```

I have another table name **tbl_subfolder**

```
db_id db_subfoldername db_folderid
1     img               1
```

I have another table name **tbl_folderfile**

```
db_id  db_filename db_folderid
1      xxxx             1
2      yyyy             1
```

I want to select all information related with folder id

i do a query like this

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_subfolder JOIN tbl_folderfile ON tbl_subfolder.db_folderid = tbl_folderfile.db_folderid
```

but this query give me a result like this

**img  xxx img  yyy**

but the result i want are like this

**img xxx yyy**

How can i solve this ??

Comment: any suggestion ?!